# How do I define a new command in algorithmicx

Tags: macros, algorithms, algorithmicx

The `algorithmicx` package defines two commands `\Require` and `\Ensure` for providing initial conditions. However, I'd like some custom commands such as `\Assume`, `\Define`, `\Input`, etc. At present, I merely rename the above two commands to something I want, like:

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input}}
```

However, this is not really a good solution because

1. it clutters the algorithm code and what I see in LaTeX is not what is output, which can be confusing if I forget to read the preamble.
2. it's not useful when the number of custom definitions needed is more than the predefined ones.

How do I define a custom command equivalent to the above two in the `algorithmicx` package (I'm using `algpseudocode`)? The examples in the documentation seem to cover blocks like `for ... end`, etc., and not individual statements.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In the documentation you can find `\algnewcommand`. In relation `\Require` is defined as

```
\algnewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Require:}}
```

So you can do:

```
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{INPUT:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicinput{\textbf{INPUT:}}
\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[\algorithmicinput]}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\INPUT foo
\Require $x\ge5$
\Ensure $x\le-5$
\Statex
\While{$x>-5$}
\State $x\gets x-1$
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks :) I tried defining `\algorithmicinput` with `\algnewcommand` like you have, but my mistake was to follow it up with `\newcommand` without `\item`, which only messed up the layout. Now I realize what I should've done.

Comment: Why do we need two level of definition, what is the dfference when we simply write :`\algnewcommand\INPUT{\item[{\textbf{INPUT:}}]}`

Comment: @DurgaDatta: The advantages is the lower error rate. With `\algorithmicinput` you simple define the string to print. The command `\INPUT` also contains relevant definition -- in this simple case only `\item`. So the user can simply redefine `\algorithmicinput`.

Comment: When I try to use this answer to define a command that I want to use within a certain block, my new command ignores the indentation that it should obey.